# Ресурсоемкость запросов в БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных, нагрузка

Есть таблица в MYSQL c полями "id", "категория", "год", "картинка" и другие
На сайте выводятся различные блоки:
Например, блок "Другие посты". Делается запрос "Показать 4 записи из таблицы такой-то, где поле Картинка" не пустое."
То есть получается это 4 рандомных записи, у которых есть поле "картинка" не пустая.

Страниц очень много (более 50000 записей) и нагрузка на впс стала очень большая. Помимо оптимизации БД Насколько я понял, эти запросы делают очень большую нагрузку.

Если я этот запрос уточню другими критериями
Например, сделаю запрос "Показать 4 записи из таблицы такой-то, где поле "картинка" не пустое И "год" равен 2018 И "категория" равна "определенная_категория" И "id" < 200"

Получается я сузил поиск, для вывода записей, но сделал много запросов.
Вопрос: Во втором случае нагрузка будет создаваться меньше или больше? Насколько сильно?

Comment: Подозреваю, без конкретного create table и без конкретных explain select ответить что-то конкретное будет затруднительно

Comment: Почему вы сделали много запросов ? (Запрос это `select ... from ...`, если вы добавили что то в where, то запрос у вас все равно один, просто условий больше). Почитайте про индексы. Если по какому то из указанных условий поиска будет индекс поиск будет моментален. Если подходящих индексов не будет, то будет полный перебор таблицы, что безумно медленно на большой таблице. А количество условий практически не влияет. Так же почитайте про команду `explain` надо смотреть план выполнения запроса что бы понимать что с ним не так

Comment: И очень интересно каким образом вы получаете 4 рандомных записи. Быстрых способов их получения из всех возможных, да еще не на всем множестве таблицы, а по условиям практически не существует

Comment: *Если я этот запрос* Этот - это который? скорости сферического коня в вакууме и на воздухе сравнить нереально... Структуру таблиц и explaint текстов запросов - в студию.